# ¿Variable no definida en PHP a la hora de enviar datos a MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario y tengo que meter los datos de este formulario, el caso es que al hace el submit me dice que no existen esas variables que aparecen en la imagen donde muestro el error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pràctica DOM3</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zxcvbn/4.2.0/zxcvbn.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zxcvbn/4.2.0/zxcvbn.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <style>
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                /*text-decoration: underline;*/
            }
            #ultimsEstudisCursatsLabel {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            #submitFormButton {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
            }
            #resetFormButton {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
            }
            meter {
                margin: 0 auto 1em;
                width: 100%;
                height: .5em;
            }

            .errorCiteClass {
                display: block;
                margin: auto;
                text-align: center;
                color: red;
            }

            meter[value="1"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: red; }
            meter[value="2"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: yellow; }
            meter[value="3"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: orange; }
            meter[value="4"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: green; }

      #cite9 {
        display: none;
        color: red;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Inscripció CF Informàtica Marianao</h2>
            <br>
            <form method="post" action="script.php" id="formulari">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="input1">Nom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" id="inputNom" placeholder="Escriu el teu nom ..." />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Primer cognom</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="primerCognom" class="form-control" id="inputCognom1" placeholder="Escriu el primer cognom ..." />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Segon cognom</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="segonCognom" class="form-control" id="inputCognom2" placeholder="Escriu el segon cognom ..." />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Data naixament </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="date" name="dataNaixement" class="form-control" id="inputNaixament" placeholder="Selecciona la teva data de naixament ..."/>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Escriu el teu correu electrònic ..."/>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Telèfon</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="tel" name="telefon" class="form-control" id="inputTelefon" placeholder="Escriu el teu telèfon ..."/>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">DNI</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="dni" class="form-control" id="inputDni" placeholder="Escriu el teu DNI ..." />
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label col-sm-2">Cicle formatiu</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" name="cicleFormatiu">
                                <option value="smx">SMX: Sistemes Microinformàtics i Xarxes</option>
                                <option value="asix">ASIX: Administració de Sistemes Informàtics en Xarxa</option>
                                <option value="dam">DAM: Desenvolupament d'Aplicacions Multiplataforma</option>
                                <option value="daw">DAW: Desenvolupament d'Aplicacions Web</option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" id="ultimsEstudisCursatsLabel">Últims estudis cursats</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="ultimEstudis" value="eso" class="custom-control-input">ESO</label><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="ultimEstudis" value="batx" class="custom-control-input">Batxillerat</label><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="ultimEstudis" value="cfgm" class="custom-control-input">CF Grau Mitjà</label><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="ultimEstudis" value="cfgs">CF Grau Superior</label><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="ultimEstudis" value="altres">Altres</label><br><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Usuari</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputUsuari" name="usuari" />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contrasenya</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="contrasenya" class="form-control" />
                        <meter max="4" id="password-strength-meter"></meter>
                <cite id="cite9">Contrassenya incorrecta.</cite>
                        <p id="password-strength-text"></p>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Torna a escriure la contrasenya</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="password" name="contrasenyaCheck" id="contrasenyaCheck" class="form-control" disabled/>
                        <meter max="4" id="password-strength-meter"></meter>
                        <p id="password-strength-text"></p>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Observacions</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="observacions" id="textarea" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                        <div>
                            <cite id="count"></cite>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Termes i condicions</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="termesCondicions" value="yes" class="form-check-input" >Consulta <span><a href="condicions.html" target="_blank">aquí</a></span> els termes i condicions.<br></label>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-success" id="submitFormButton">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" class="btn btn-primary" id="resetFormButton">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

  define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mp06-form');
  $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

  $nom = $_POST["nom"];
  $primerCognom = $_POST["primerCognom"];
  $segonCognom = $_POST["segonCognom"];
  $dataNaixement = $_POST["dataNaixement"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $telefon = $_POST["telefon"];
  $dni = $_POST["dni"];
  $cicleFormatiu = $_POST["cicleFormatiu"];
  $ultimEstudis = $_POST["ultimEstudis"];
  $usuari = $_POST["usuari"];
  $contrasenya = $_POST["contrasenya"];
  $observacions = $_POST["observacions"];

  // Insertar datos.

  $insertar = "INSERT INTO register (nom, cognom1, cognom2, naixement, mail, telefon, dni, cicleformatiu, estudis, usuari, password, observacions) VALUES($nom, $primerCognom, $segonCognom, $dataNaixement, $email, $telefon, $dni, $cicleFormatiu, $ultimEstudis, $usuari, $contrasenya, $observacions)");

  // Ejecutar consulta.

  $resultado = mysqli_query ($db, $insertar);

  if (!$resultado) {
    echo "Error al registrarse.";
  }
  else {
    echo "Usuario registrado exitosamente.";
  }

  // Cerramos conexión.

  mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

El error que me salta es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver las variables están declaradas, no entiendo por qué me salta ese error.

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Comment: ¿phpMyAdmin o MySQL?

Comment: Perdón, lo hago a través de MySQL pero estoy utilizando PhpMyAdmin. Estoy trabajando con XAMPP en Windows (Apache + MySQL).

Comment: Precisamente en la ruta que aparece en el `in .....` debes verificar que tanto `script.php` como el archivo que contiene el formulario están en la misma ruta. Lo que está ocurriendo creo, es que están en rutas distintas pues las variables que menciona el error están definidas en ese archivo, no tiene caso que de ese error. Parece que el `action` apunta a otro archivo en otra ruta.

Comment: Hola! No he probado tu código. Pero, a primera vista se percibe un fallo elemental: los elementos imput de tipos **radio**, **checkbox** y **select** no envían valores cuando no se ha hecho selección de modo que tu lectura de la superglobal $_POST no es correcta. **Debes hacer:** `$variable = isset($_POST[$clave]) ? $_POST[$clave] : default_para_clave;`

Comment: No entiendo porque te repite que las variables están en la línea 15 si cada variable está en líneas distintas.

Comment: Estás seguro que el código que mostraste es el que estás usando en la imagen?

Comment: @$nom = $_POST["nom"]; intenta definiendo la variable de este modo, el error de todas las variables en la linea 15 es porque el interprete de php no ha podido evaluar las siguientes variables por ende queda el ultimo mensaje de error, intenta colocando un valor en código a esa variable y veras que el mensaje cambia ,  $nom = 'valordeprueba'; , la ultima opción que puedes intentar es evaluar si realmente desde el formulario se están enviando los datos, usa la herramienta de desarrollo de firefox Ctrl+Shift+I , ahí puedes inspeccionar el posteo de los datos desde el formulario.

Comment: tienes un error al final de la construcción de la consulta, $observacions)"); revisa.

Comment: ya verifique el posteo de los datos y esta correcto, los datos salen de la pagina inicial, el tema esta en el script.php, intenta con los datos que te envié y me avisas.

Comment: Al final tuve que entregar el trabajo así porqué no había manera ... ¡Igualmente muchas gracias por la ayuda a TODOS! Un saludo.